# Is it possible to use ArrayFire in Juliabox?

Tags: julia, arrayfire

Is it possible to use ArrayFire in Juliabox? If it is possible how can I do it?

-I downloaded the installer and I installed ArrayFire following the installation steps.

-I included the `PATH` of the installed folder through push! (`LOAD_PATH`, "Path")

-I installed the package via Pkg.add("ArrayFire")

-Finally when I tried to use Pkg.test, I got the following error:

**Pkg.test("ArrayFire")**

```
INFO: Testing ArrayFire
ERROR: LoadError: error compiling init: could not load library "libaf"
libaf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
....
```

Comment: I wouldn't think so. ArrayFire needs the ArrayFire binary `libaf` which has to be installed separately, and I am not sure if you'd have the capabilities to do that. Even if you could get that setup, I don't think it has GPUs?

Comment: I have installed ArrayFire in the Julia command version, and it works fine, juliabox works with a remote computer, and I would like to work in this environment.